# Endless corrupted sstable after EC2 image restore from AMI backup

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra version 3.11.4, many corrupted sstable files showing in system.log after service restart, and we tried to use AMI backup to restore EC2 server, but the corrupted message showed up too, we tried everything, no matter nodetool scrub, sstablescrub, remove corrupted files then repair, seems corrupted files won't stop to show up.

Is there anyone have encounter this before? Any help will be much thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply restore a Cassandra node by recovering from an AMI backup because it will have a different database state compared to when it was running.

If your data is stored on EBS, you can replace the EC2 instance then mount the EBS to the same Cassandra `data/` directory so the node will start in the same state that is persisted on the EBS volume.

If the above method isn't available to you, you will need to replace the node "with itself" using the `replace_address` option [documented here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is not the same situation here, I'm familiar with `replace_address` or recovering from EBS, my issue is sstable was messed up

Comment: Correct, because with an AMI backup, the SSTables are NOT in a consistent state so they are not recoverable. Cheers!